# Cant compile "Hello world" to .exe file

Tags: python-3.x

recently i have decided I would like to start learning python. I have started with installing IDE PyCharm. I have made some basic programs and now I would like to compile them into .exe file as Im used to from C++. So I have installed pip and then pyinstalled. I have added path to pyinstalled in Windows path variables. Now the pyinstaller is working but i cant compile any programs. Im always getting the same error:

```
41 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
41 INFO: Python: 3.8.3
41 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
43 INFO: wrote C:\Users\zilin\PycharmProjects\TestProject\main.spec
44 INFO: UPX is not available.
44 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\zilin\\PycharmProjects\\TestProject',
'C:\\Users\\zilin\\PycharmProjects\\TestProject']
45 INFO: checking Analysis
45 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
45 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
46 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
50 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1467 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
1467 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib'
2321 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
2386 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
yield
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 42, in check_null
raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 1920] Systém nemůže získat přístup k souboru. -translation- system cannot access the file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\zilin\PycharmProjects\TestProject\main.spec", line 6, in <module>
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 393, in assemble
self.binaries.extend(bindepend.Dependencies([('', python, '')],
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 228, in Dependencies
for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 404, in getAssemblyFiles
for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 355, in getAssemblies
res = GetManifestResources(pth)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1007, in GetManifestResources
return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 170, in GetResources
hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\zilin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'Systém nemůže získat přístup k souboru.') -translation- system cannot access the file
```

Comment: Did you add the python3 shebang at the top? :`#!/usr/bin/env python3`